# Login page for asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to stored procedure and asp.net world.
I have 'USER' table with three fields,
`@id`,`@username`,`@password`
I have created login page with two textbox, if the username and password is correct it is redirected to next page.
But how to pass @id value to next page, so that i can display 'USER INFORMATION' in that page.

all i want is writing asp.net c# code for the store procedure .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how to pass @id value to next page

You can store `Id` in session variable. Check session variable on page_Load event if it is not null load the information you want.

> I am new to stored procedure

Why do you want to use `store procedure` for login?

Comment: It's obvious the OP is a little lost but, there's many reasons to use a stored proc for login.  One obvious one is that many places insist on all SQL to run as stored procs, which has a number of advantages, especially with regard to security.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're reinventing the wheel. Is there any particular reason you're hoping to roll your own login system? ASP.NET provides a very good login system, which might be worth looking into.

The following link shows you how to use ASP.NET basic user login system in your website
[Walkthrough: Creating an ASP.NET Web Site with Basic User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

As a side note, if you do decide to develop your own login system for what ever reason PLEASE do not store the users password plain text! This is considered EXTREMELY bad practice. What you should do is use a hashing algorithm (NOT encryption) like SHA512 on the password and then store the result of that. Then when you go to login, you hash the password they are trying to login with and compare it to what you have stored. Ideally you should also [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) your hash but at the very least you should be hashing it.

Answer (score 0):

i Think this litle tutorial is all that you need :)

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/06/login-page-form-example-in-aspnet.html

Use Postback to get the userInput. Then send the data to your stored procedure.
If password correct Redirect and set session/cookie-information.

else just set an error message on the site.

more reading on Postback and viewstate.
http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa051705a.htm